# How do I change UEFI boot order when the BIOS (the firmware) does not have that option?

Tags: boot, bios, multi-boot, uefi, bootloader

I want to change the boot order to default to rEFInd but the system always boots to Windows 10 and I have to use F10 method to boot into Linux via grub and rEFInd. I want to boot into rEFInd by default because of the tools and also because Linux is pretty stable. How do I change the boot order?

- BIOS (the firmware) doesn't have the option to change boot order (Intel DG41RQ).
- I have already tried `bcdedit`, EasyUEFI, and `efibootmgr` methods, but they didn't work.

Comment: UEFI is not BIOS, it replaced it long time ago. It's a mistake keep calling it BIOS, if you have one you don't have the other. But the firmware (UEFI) must have the boot order setting somewhere, unless you enabled CSM (Legacy) only in which case it'll behave like the old BIOS. Please [edit] and post details about the computer.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia There's no "CSM" option available. And I already changed the boot mode from Legacy to UEFI (I think that was implied).

Also, edited the question wrt 'firmware'. Also, what should I post details about more?

Comment: Weird thing, you mentioned " Intel DG41RQ" which, according to this https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/39683/intel-desktop-board-dg41rq.html is from 2008 so I'm almost certain it is BIOS, not UEFI. So, when you press F10 it allows you to select a different drive or what are the exact options you see there?

Comment: The point here ^^^ is to try to understand how are you actually booting. I'm afraid you using concepts and methods that aren't applicable to your hardware because in all certainty you don't have UEFI, you have the old BIOS. Funny that's usually the other way around, people trying to apply their "old ways" to new UEFI based computers.

Comment: I am certain I am using UEFI, it has the option for UEFI, I used `mbr2gpt` to use UEFI boot with Windows and also rEFInd works only with UEFI iirc.

Comment: F10 listed my two drives, then `INTERNAL EFI SHELL`, then `Windows Bootloader`, then `kali` (which's grub), then `rEFInd Boot Manager`. I did some unfortunate shit and managed to delete the Windows Bootloader entry but the Internal EFI shell boots into Windows. I can re enter the Windows Bootloader with EasyUEFI though, that's not the problem, but it shows that I'm using UEFI.

Comment: So you should be able ro select refind as the first boot priority or not? Of course, by opening the UEFI settings

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia That's why the question. I will probably try out deleting all entries but rEFInd if possible and then readding them....